# Assigning values based on position of column

Tags: r

I have this data set that looks like this:

```
ID  Conversion  date_time
1   0          22/08/2016 00:28
1   1          22/08/2016 00:09
2   0          22/08/2016 00:50
2   0          22/08/2016 00:52
2   0          22/08/2016 00:11
```

I want to create a for loop where, based on the Unique ID #, I want to order the date_time column and assign a value 1 onwards in Ascending order. So it would look something like this:

```
ID  Conversion  date_time
1     0            1
1     1            2
2     0            1
2     0            2
2     0            3
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID  Conversion  date_time
                 1   0          22/08/201600:28
                 1   1          22/08/201600:09
                 2   0          22/08/201600:50
                 2   0          22/08/201600:52
                 2   0          22/08/201600:11")



library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, date_time1 := 1:.N, by = ID]
df[, date_time := NULL]
setnames(df, "date_time1", "date_time")

    ID Conversion date_time
1:  1          0         1
2:  1          1         2
3:  2          0         1
4:  2          0         2
5:  2          0         3
```